# PHP MySQL stop loop at next available number

Tags: php, mysql

i've got a database with the folowing info:

```
--------------
id | Book | Names
1  | 1    | Tom
2  | 8    | James
3  | 10   | Tom
4  | 2    | Tom
5  | 17   | James
6  | 2    | James
7  | 9    | James
8  | 7    | Tom
9  | 8    | Tom
```

This table shows books read by "Tom" and "James".

These are the requirements i need:

1. to show the next book not read. (eg. Tom's would be '3' and James's '1')
2. to skip book '1', '10' and '15' as these are no longer available. (so in James's case, the next book would be '3')
3. if it cannot be sequential, any random book not read will do as well.

here's what i did:

```
$sql = "Select * FROM books Group By names"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE names = '" . $row["names"]. "' ORDER BY book ASC"; 
            $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
            if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                $newbook = '1';
                // output data of each row
                while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

                    if ($row1["book"] == $newbook) {
                        echo "Exist<br><br>";
                        $newbook = $newbook+ 1;
                    } else {
                        if ($row1["book"] == '1' || $row1["book"] == '10' || $row1["book"] == '17') {
                            $newbook= $newbook+ 1;

                        } else {
                            echo "Add".$newbook."<br><br>";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how far i've got. All help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you left out SELECT from the first sql string. what output do you get from that script?

Comment: i got 2 results from the first select. Tom, and James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, a calendar table approach might be a good solution to handle this problem completely in MySQL.  First define a sequence table, containing the values from 1 to the highest book ID (I call this table `seq_table`).  Then, to find the lowest book not read by a given user, a simple left join will do the trick:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.Book) AS next_book
FROM seq_table t1
LEFT JOIN books t2
    ON t1.Book = t2.Book AND
       t2.Names = 'Tom'
WHERE
    t2.Book IS NULL;
```

If you instead wanted to choose a random book not read by Tom, then we can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.Book AS next_book
FROM seq_table t1
LEFT JOIN books t2
    ON t1.Book = t2.Book AND
       t2.Names = 'Tom'
WHERE
    t2.Book IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Random doesn't work though. it chooses all books read / not read. if you could amend it that would be great

Comment: @AndrewTsang My second query absolutely returns a single random record.  Perhaps your data has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

you will need another table to store available books let say `books` table

```
---------------------------------------------
id | Book_Title             | Available
---------------------------------------------
1  | One million promises   | no
2  | Two towers             | yes
3  | Three musketeers       | yes
4  | 4th Avenue Cafe        | yes
5  | Famous Five            | yes
6  | Six million dollar man | yes
7  | Seven Stars            | yes
8  | Eighth Paladin         | yes
9  | Ninth Heaven           | yes
```

lets say that your read books table is named `read_books`, you can get the next book to read by Tom with this query:

```
select min(id) from books where Available='yes' and id not in (select book from read_books where names = 'Tom')
```

Comment: the 'book' table is the read_books table you are referring to. i've got another table for available books which can be linked via book id